# Is it possible to setup a CAN-BUS Arduino Shield to communicate with SocketCAN for UNIX?

Tags: arduino-uno, can-bus

I have an Arduino + SparkFun CAN shield, and I was hoping to set it up to work with candump on an Ubuntu system. Is this doable, or is candump made specifically for raspberry Pi's?

Comment: What's candump? How about providing some links, eg. to the shield and whatever candump is.

Comment: what do you mean "set it up to work with candump"? What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to use an Arduino to expose a CAN bus to the linux candump?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Normally you would write a linux kernel driver to communicate with your device (arduino) following your own protocol, but SocketCAN provides by default a way to interface with [Lawicel](http://www.can232.com/) dongles, whose communication protocol is publicly available: [CANUSB / CAN232 protocol](http://www.can232.com/docs/canusb_manual.pdf).

Many people have built arduino sketches that implement this protocol so you can use your arduino with SocketCAN in Linux (candump, cansniff...) as if it were a Lawicel dongle.

You may find this useful:

https://github.com/autowp/arduino-canhacker

https://github.com/kahiroka/slcanuino